# canonical source not found for jessie debian

Tags: linux, debian, canonical-link

I allways get this error:

```
name@debian-name:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for name: 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com jessie InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com jessie Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.canonical.com jessie Release
Err http://archive.canonical.com jessie/partner amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Err http://archive.canonical.com jessie/partner i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Ign http://archive.canonical.com jessie/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com jessie/partner Translation-en
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable InRelease
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://repo.vivaldi.com stable Release
Get:1 http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main amd64 Packages [8,859 B]
Get:2 http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main i386 Packages [6,766 B]
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo.vivaldi.com stable/main Translation-en
Fetched 15.6 kB in 2s (6,035 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch 
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/jessie/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch 
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/jessie/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I removed all sources of the sources.list file besides the canonical and I still get this error.
So the sources.list has only the following source:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jessie partner
```

Why can't it find it?

Comment: Canonical makes Ubuntu, and you have this source list in Debian?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are sure you have Debian Jessie, you should use Debian list, not Ubuntu. For example, here is the default source list for German location:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Comment: I have debian jessie. Should I still replace jessie by trusty?